# Is it possible to filter out filter IOS push notification purely on client side?

Tags: android, ios, apple-push-notifications

Assume we have a football app, user have interests with team inter and milan.
but in the app, he only want to receive the push notification from inter.

Can we still sent out the push notification to user for both team inter and milan.
but do the filter work on client side to only display the message for inter?

Comment: There are two types of iOS push, for a foreground push to the user no you can't. For a silent  push to the app yes you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, if you are using Firebase to deliver notifications it depends what payload does your notification has.

Basically, there are two types of notification payloads: notification and data. Here is an example illustrating notification with both types of payload.

```
 {
  "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "great match!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "icon" : "myicon"
 },
  "data" : {
    "Nick" : "Mario",
    "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
 }
}
```

If your notification contains both types of payload or only "notification" type, there is no way to handle if notification gets displayed when app is in background.
If your application contains only "data" type of payload than you can handle if notification gets displayed no matter if application is in background or in foreground.